# Running Norton Internet Security 2009 from command line

Tags: scripting, anti-virus, symantec

I'd like to be able to run Norton Internet Security 2009 from the command line and have the status of that scan set the errorlevel in Windows. With older versions, you could so something like this:

```
navw32 /S /NORESULTS PathToScan
```

The "2009" version doesn't have the */NORESULTS* flag so launching navw32 immediately returns to the command line before the scan is even finished (the scan dialog is also left up and needs to be manually dismissed).

The documentation hasn't been much help -- any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer is "No"

In the past they have provided VPSCAN.EXE but it does not appear to work on newer versions of Windows or Symantec.

There is also the DoScan.exe program which can only initiate a Quick or Full scan.  It cannot scan individual files or folders.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for but I think you are absolutely right, Kevin.